Aiogram - Missing 1 required positional argument: callback()
@router.message(CommandStart())
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'main111')
async def cmd_start(message:Message,callback:CallbackQuery,):
    await callback.message.edit_text(f'Welcome here! \n It is great to see ya, {message.from_user.first_name} ! \n Here is our rights! \n 1: \n 2: \n 3:',  reply_markup=await kb.mainFunction())
    await message.edit_text(f'Welcome here! \n It is great to see ya, {message.from_user.first_name} ! \n Here is our rights! \n 1: \n 2: \n 3:',  reply_markup=await kb.mainFunction()) 

Пробовал без последней строки, но не работает
Ошибка:
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 49, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 170, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 162, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\app\middleware.py", line 12, in __call__
    result = await handler(event,data)#handler(обработчик)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\programming\pythonProject\MrPresidentVSCODE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
                 ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cmd_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'


На этом сайте принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке. Переведите свой вопрос, или воспользуйтесь англоязычным сайтом.

Пожалуйста, приложите полный текст ошибки.

В функции обработки колбэков в аргументах должен быть только callback, без message. В callback и так хранится вся информация о сообщении, к которому была прикреплена кнопка
Ваш код должен выглядеть так:
@router.message(CommandStart())
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'main111')
async def cmd_start(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text(f'Welcome here! \n It is great to see ya, {callback.from_user.first_name} ! \n Here is our rights! \n 1: \n 2: \n 3:',  reply_markup=await kb.mainFunction())


Спасибо, Mipsirint.
Вставляя ваш код вылетела ошибка
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'. Did you mean: 'message_id'?
На время заменил последнюю строку на
await callback.answer...
Как можно исправить действующую проблему?

@MaksimPaulau Вы точно в своём коде с CallbackQuery работаете, а не с Message?
